# How do I make a control object animate where I want in a scene?

Tags: animation, modifiers, objects, baking

I'm making an audio visualizer and using a cast modifier to animate an object. I have another object set as the control object. The control object is set to "Bake Sound to F-Curves".

I want to center the control object on the grid. My problem is that after moving the control object to where I want on the grid and pressing play animation, the control object moves back to where it was originally. How do I make the control object animate where I want it to?

Comment: Hi ace, welcome to Blender SE.  Can you post a .blend?  I'm having a hard time understanding your approach to this Audio Visualization.  Are you trying to center the control object on only one axis?  If that's the case, you'd best jump into the F-Curve editor and find the axis you want centered.

Comment: Yes, I want the control object to move only along the z-axis. The problem is that when I play the animation the control object makes a short jump along the x-axis.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I had to set the x-axis in the F-Curve editor.